# Unable to resolve network connection on android studio emulator

Tags: android

I wanted to run an app on emulator in android studio. But was unable to access network on emulator.

[image: I wanted to run an app on emulator in android studio. But was unable to access network on emulator.]

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have done so far? Otherwise we can have no idea what is going wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Haha.. Yeah, I was about to ask the same

Comment: create a new emulator with android Marshmallow(This worked for me and not with other OS), your emulator doesn't have access to internet as I can see a cross over LTE, also check for DNS of your laptop and maybe set it to 8.8.8.8